# Using RESTful Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, rest

This is a really simple question, I am just a beginner in RESTful api.

I have an ASP.NET MVC website which calls a RESTful api (ASP.NET WebApiController) that contains CRUD commands on some objects. Note that the RESTful api is still in development by another programmer and the objects/methods could change.

Up until now I was using regular WebServices which generated interfaces and objects according to the WebService's api. so each time something changed I would simply update the service reference. I can't use them now since I don't want the WebServices to be bound to my website.

My question is : is it ok to sent to the RESTful api hard-coded json objects (Example - for an animal class which has name and type I will create a json object {name:"lucky",type:"dog"})?

What if the objects/Methods change? (Like if the animal's name property will be called Name). How am I supposed to know this without an interface specifing the api?

Comment: you would not possibly know unless the api documentation is published from api. I think web api does that automatically. There should be a help link in your api url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your concerns are about [Versioning RESTful Services](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2012/11/09/versioning-restful-services/) and about [Creating Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages)